# Is the higher $Q$-factor of a laser cavity the better?

Tags: laser, laser-cavity

A high $Q$ cavity means that the light will travel between the cavity mirrors many times before leaving the cavity. The more times the light reflects, the longer the gain medium effectively extends.

It seems to me that a high $Q$-factor is always better. Is there any drawback of a ultra-high $Q$ cavity, especially for laser applications?

Answer (score 1):

Just a couple thoughts. For CW applications, A better cavity gets you a narrower laser linewidth which is desirable in many cases without changing the power very much once the laser is lasing. However occasionally you want a broadband, or more incoherent, laser source, and one way to achieve that is with a bad cavity. Depending on how the laser is constructed, e.g. if it's being driven by a different external laser source, the cavity quality might effect how easy it is to drive the laser.

I don't work with pulsed lasers, but the situation there is eminently more complicated. A common type of pulsed laser is a Q-switched laser where the cavity Q is actively or passively modified in order to achieve pulsed operation. I'm not sure there's a simple answer when it comes to these more complicated schemes.

Comment: *For the vast majority of applications* is just not true. I do not actually know what would be the best answer for the question at hand, but your answer does not seem appropriate in any sense. You limited your answer to some form of CW lasers, which aren't even the most used. I would just point to this website [q-factor](https://www.rp-photonics.com/q_factor.html) and let OP read other articles there as well.

Comment: That's true I was thinking of CW lasers. I'm not sure that CW lasers aren't the I'm not sure it makes sense to answer the question in the context of pulsed lasers considering techniques like Q-switching or mode locking where the operation of the cavity is qualitatively different than in the other cases and which the OP clearly wasn't thinking about. I'm not sure that the answer actually doesn't hold for pulsed lasers, but I know much less about those so I should temper my answer. Also, I'm fairly certain that cw diode lasers are going to be the most commonly used laser.